# It doesn't work to get data from a table to use in factories

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get data from two tables, to use within a factory to register. They are foreign keys.
There is data in these tables, but apparently, it can't get anything.

Factory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class OrderItemFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = OrderItem::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $orders = Order::pluck('id')->get()->toArray();
        $products = Product::pluck('id')->get()->toArray();
        
        return [
            'order_id' =>  $this->faker->randomElement($orders),
            'product_id' => $this->faker->randomElement($products),
        ];
    }
}
```

The seeder is very simple `OrderItem::factory()->count(10)->create();`

When executing the seeder that receives this factory, it gives the following error

`Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\programming\gitlab\Petronas\api-base-cadastral\databas    e\factories\OrderItemFactory.php on line 26 and at least 1 expected`

Answer (score 0):

The:

```
->get()->toArray();
```

Is too much, pluck returns already a Collection. Depends on your version of Laravel, but you can directly use:

```
Order::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Even can try:

```
// toArray() or all() should do the same for a plucked Collection
Order::pluck('id')->all();
```